# Opening and processing multiple files

Tags: python

im learning file input/output and i was wondering how i would go about opening multiple files with a similar name. for example hw-data-01 , hw-data-02.....hw-data-99, i need to open these files and process them but im having trouble just opening them at all. here is what ive tried,

```
i = 00
while i < 100 :
    f = open("hw09-data-%d.csv", "r") % i
    for line in f :
        print line
    i = i + 1
```

problem is when i hit run to see if all files are read and printed, it says the directory cannot be found. im pretty sure its because 00 + 1 = 1 and not 01 which is the way the files are stored. im not really sure what to do now, i heard my teacher talking about the `glob module` but he did a really brief example and i dont know how to apply it here. any help would be appreciated

Comment: maybe i can use some sort of matching method so if the file reads "hw-data-", it will read it and print it, but now would i know when to stop it

Comment: You need to isolate the problem. You *think* it's because of the incorrect filename. Okay great. `print` out the filename you're trying to open and see if it actually exists. If not, adjust the code that generates the filename, so it's opening the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

Two problems with this code:

```
open("hw09-data-%d.csv", "r") % i
```

First of all, you're trying to apply the string formatting operator `%` to the file object that `open()` returns. You mean to be applying it to the filename string:

```
open("hw09-data-%d.csv" % i, "r")
```

Secondly, you mention filenames with two digit numbers, like `hw-data-01`.  `"%d" % 1` is going to return `"1"` though, not `"01"` as you want.  To fix this, you need to specify that you want a two-digit, zero-padded format, with `"%02d"`

```
open("hw09-data-%02d.csv" % i, "r")
```

- [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

---

Additional notes / critiques:

```
i = 00
```

You probably did this to try and fix your previous bug. But this accomplishes nothing in that way. In fact, this could be misleading if it weren't zero, because numbers that start with a leading zero are interpreted in octal.  For example `0777` is actually the decimal number 511.

This is Python, not C! Iterate like a Python master:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    with open("hw09-data-%02d.csv" % i, "r") as f:
       for line in f :
           print line
```

Comment: to avoid an empty line after every line in a file, you could add a comma: `print line,` (`sys.stdout.softspace`-based hack. Mind the last line in a file without a newline character case) or `print line.rstrip("\n")`.

Answer (score 2):

The [glob module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) is very handy, I suggest reading up on it and playing with it to learn how to use it. That's a huge part of being a good programmer, being able to read the documentation and apply the new material.

Since you mention a teacher I assume this is homework, so I won't give you the answer. However, here's a quick example:

```
>>> import glob
>>> myfiles = glob.glob('2013-07-*.TCX')

>>> myfiles
['2013-07-27-090736.TCX', '2013-07-28-120243.TCX', '2013-07-28-123000.TCX', '2013-07-29-134417.TCX', '2013-07-29-141027.TCX', '2013-07-30-112848.TCX', '2013-07-30-115900.TCX', '2013-07-30-131222.TCX']
```

Glob uses pattern matching to grab all the files that match the string you send it. In this case I have a directory with dated files, and I want a list of all the files from July, 2013. Glob will grab every filename that starts with '2013-07-', ends with '.TCX', and has (basically) anything in between. You might need a fancier/more specific pattern if your files aren't so neatly labeled, but that's the basic idea. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

If you want file names to be 00, 01, ... 09, 10, 11, ... 99 you can try this :

```
i = 00
while i < 10 :
    if i<10 :
        f = open("hw09-data-0{0}.csv".format(i))
    else :
        f = open("hw09-data-{0}.csv".format(i))
    for line in f :
        print line
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Use the features the language has to offer, like zero-padding in string formatting.